# What is the best way to distinguish the current buffer is location list or quickfix list?

Tags: vim

I have an autocmd, if `ft` is `qf`, it is gonna call some functions to modify the quickfix list by `get/setqflist()`

I know there are another pair of functions `get/setloclist()`, to handle the location list.

My problem is,  how to know if the current buffer is `qf-list` or `location-list` (They both have `filetype` `qf`) so that I know which functions should be called?

so far what I can think of is, assume both loc and qf lists are not empty, do some change on qf-list, and compare with current buffer, if the current buffer is changed too, it is qf-list, otherwise it should be location list. Finally roll back the changes. But I feel it is stupid... there should be better way to make the decision.

Did I miss some function/flag/variable ?

Comment: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/detect-QuickFix-window-list-or-LocationList-td4952180.html Take a look at this thread. (The second one would ideally be what you want but I don't think it works...). The person eventually settled on `empty(getloclist(0))` to see if the location list for the current buffer was empty if it was assume quick fix.

Comment: @FDinoff yes in my case both lists could be empty and could be filled data.

Answer (score 14):

Just for new comers: as of now, there is `getwininfo()` which returns dicts containing key `quickfix` which can be used for the check. Also note the `loclist` key.

Since `getwininfo` returns a list of dict, you may use:

```
getwininfo(win_getid())[0]['quickfix']
```

which is 1 when it is a quickfix or location list window. And

```
getwininfo(win_getid())[0]['loclist']
```

which is 1 only when it is a location list.

In short:

```
 getwininfo() value:  'quickfix'    'loclist' 
------------------------------------------------
quickfix list            1              0
location list            1              1
```

Answer (score 6):

The `w:quickfix_title` variable tells you what command was used to generate the list displayed in the window. If the first letter after the colon is an `l` you are in location list.

Comment: +1 for the variable. I don't know this before. but is this way safe? I mean what if the loc/qf list was set by some script, like setqflist(). it will show this function name... then I need check the key word `qf` or `loc` in function name. I don't know if there are other cases..

Comment: And there is another problem, if the quicklist is empty, e.g. opened by `:copen`, reading this var will throw exception. but it seems that we cannot open an empty location list.. I mean open the empty location list window manually.

Answer (score 2):

**There is a way to do this. Here's how:**

You get the output of the "ls" command, which shows you the currently active buffers. Then you simply search that output for the existence/state of whatever window you want.

The example below will tell you if either the Quickfix or Location list window is focused:

```
function! example()
    exec 'redir @a | ls | redir END'
    if match(@a,'%a-  "\[Location List\]"') >= 0
            exec 'echo "Location list focused!"'
    elseif match(@a,'%a-  "\[Quickfix List\]"') >= 0
            exec 'echo "Quickfix list focused!"'
    else
            exec 'echo "Neither Location or Quicklist focused!"'
    endif
endfunction
```

I appreciate you asking this question and I noted that you even went so far as to try to find help elsewhere: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/detect-QuickFix-window-list-or-LocationList-td4952180.html.

I looked around the internet too, and found nothing. I think this answer should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way I've found, is to store the current window number, then issue a `:copen` command. If the active window number changes, you were in the location list and not the quickfix list. If it doesn't change, you were already in the quickfix list.

You also want to store the number of open windows, and compare that to the new number of open windows. Then you can close the quickfix window if it wasn't already open.

Finally you can jump back to the location list (if needed) using the stored window number and `wincmd w`.