# How to distinguish quickfix and location list buffers?

Tags: vim

I have following code in my Vim script:

```
    for buf_i in getbufinfo({'buflisted':1})
        " If buf_i is quickfix list buffer do one thing
        " ...
        " If buf_i is location list buffer do another thing
        "...
    endfor
```

How can I distinguish quickfix and location list buffers? `&buftype='quickfix'` for both. Or, may be you know, how to get quickfix and location list bufnr?

UPD: Method proposed by Liu Sha in [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522086/what-is-the-best-way-to-distinguish-the-current-buffer-is-location-list-or-quick) is good and moreover I know another which gives result what I need: `winbufnr(getqflist({'winid' : 1}).winid)`. But problem is that Vim with patch 8.1.0877 doesn't wipe out quickfix list and location list buffers after closing by `cclose` and `lclose`. So it doesn't work when window has been closed, but buffer still persists.

Comment: Especially note the answer by Liu Sha, which is the best for current Vim.

Comment: use the `getwininfo()` function and check the `loclist` and `quickfix` keys.